# Continuous dependence of basis of Tangent Space => Orientability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I recently had a homework problem, "Show that O(n), the manifold of orthogonal matrices, is orientable". I went to office hours and asked about the problem, but didn't have enough time to sufficiently supplement my understanding.

I was supposed to use the fact that if the basis of the tangent space to p in O(n) depends continuously on the point p, then the manifold is orientable.

I don't really understand how continuity of the basis of the tangent space implies that the determinants of the derivatives of the transition maps of the chart are positive. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Lie groups are *parallelizable* since you can pick a basis at a point and translate it by the group action.  That's much stronger than orientable.

Comment: I haven't studied Lie groups too closely-- just broad definitions, mainly. I'll take a look at the Wikipedia page of parallelizable, though!

Comment: For instance, while all spheres are orientable, only $S^1, S^3$, and $S^7$ are parallelizable (hard theorem).

Comment: Please explain (1) which definition of orientation you use (2) the precise meaning of "the basis of the tangent space to $p$ depends continuously on the point $p$", And what does is mean that the determinants of the derivatives of the transition maps of the chart are **oriented**? Don't you mean positive?